# MY_Controller Redirection Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter. And I am trying to set up a redirection true or false in MY_Controller.php

Once the install process is complete it should let me let me have access to the front end and back end.

But now when I go to the admin url it sends me back to install url even though it is installed how do I fix my problem. I want to have access to admin and front end after installed.

All Controllers extend MY Controller.

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->config->item('installed') !== FALSE) {
            redirect('install');    
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }

    }
}
```

Config.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Install Wizard Setup
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This checks if you have set gone through install process
| else get redirected. This corresponds with MY_Controller.php
| All Controllers Extend Class Now Renamed MY_Controller from
| MX_Controller 
| FALSE REDIRECTS TO INSTALL, TRUE HAS ACCESS TO MAIN SITE
|
*/
$config['installed'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if its TRUE means its installed,then you need to check this condition

```
if($this->config->item('installed') !== FALSE)
```

this should go like this

```
if($this->config->item('installed') == FALSE)
```

Feel free to let me know if any issues.

Comment: I all ready tried that had same issue that's why thought that might work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better option I think, it is to do redirections as route. Works fine this way now rather than in MY_Controller.

**This is in the config/route.php**

```
if (!$this->config->item('installed')) {

    $route['default_controller'] = "install/step_1/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';

} else {

    $route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/home/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';

}
```